# How to get cart items using customer id in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, quote

I am trying to get the **cart items** for particular `customer id`. I am getting products but it's displaying in **two times**.

For example: If the cart has two products here it's displaying four products, same product showing two times.

Thanks.

```
$customer_id= 4;
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
if($customer){
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)
        ->loadByCustomer($customer);
$collection = $quote->getItemsCollection();
if ($collection->count() > 0) {
    foreach( $collection as $product ) {    
        print_r($product);
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getProductId());//product id here
        if ($_product->isConfigurable()) {
            $productdata = array(
                "id" => $_product->getId(),
                "product_name" => $_product->getName(),
                "price" => number_format($_product->getPrice(),0),
                "discount_price" => $_product->getFinalPrice(),
                "review" => number_format((float)$avg*.05, 1, '.', ''),
                "image_full" => $imageUrl,
                "short_desc" => $_product->getDescription(),
                'sku'       => $_product->getSku(),
            );
        }
        $productsList[] = $productdata;
    }
    print_r($productsList);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you just put a count on your collection before anything else, how many items does it return?

Comment: Please remove **`print_r($product);`** from your code.

Comment: It's showing four,  but in admin side its showing two products only.

Comment: Hi Mohit,  I have removed print_r, still, its displaying four products instead of two.

Comment: please check my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply:**

```
$customerId = 4;
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customerId);
if($quote) {
    foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        echo $item->getProductId();
        echo $item->getSku();
        echo $item->getQty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I used array unique in PHP to get unique products in the array, I am getting unique products now. I have one more doubt, Is it possible to get selected attribute options in **getModel(sales/quote)**.  for example (size and color).

Comment: No, use `var_dump($item->getData())` you get all attributes, then from your selected attribute you can get his options. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994224/get-a-list-of-attribute-options-from-magento

Comment: $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());  ,this code is fetching selected attributes of product in cart.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below code to get all types of cart product :

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)->loadByCustomer($customer);

if($quote) {
    foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        echo $item->getProductId();
        echo $item->getSku();
        echo $item->getQty();
    }
}
```